# call a method after success post jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to call a method `uploadedImagesRefresh()` when the POST request is successful. The code works sometimes but sometimes it fails to call the `uploadedImagesRefresh()` but I must say the backend is okay and the Post requests completes successfully.

```
function refreshUploadedImages() {//this
    //function works quite well in other calls
}

$(function(){
    //
    $('.delete-img-btn').live('click', function() {

        //asign the image id from the button attribute 'img-id'
        var id= $(this).attr('img-id');
        //The data to be send via ajax the server will recieve 2 POST variables ie. 'action' and 'id'(which is the img id)
        var data={
            'pk':id,
            //call refreshUploadImages() upon succesful post
            'success':refreshUploadedImages
        };
        //The ajax request.

        $.post("/admin/image-uploader/delete/"+id , data);

    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong in the above code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a callback. That would be the third parameter for `$.post()`. That callback function gets called when the AJAX POST request is successful. In that function, you can call your function.

```
$.post("/admin/image-uploader/delete/"+id , data,function(data){
  refreshUploadedImages()
});
```

You can even be straighforward, and make your function the callback instead:

```
$.post("/admin/image-uploader/delete/"+id , data, refreshUploadedImages);
```